# audio tags no longer working

Tags: plugin-development, media, audio

On my website, I had a plugin, that displayed a media tag like `[audio src=path/file.mp3]`. It returned this tag in the HTML retruned from the shortcode function.

function init() {
add_shortcode('myshortcode', array($this, 'myshortcode_shortcode');
}
function myshortcode_shortcode() {
return '[audio src=path/file.mp3]';
}

This used to work by displaying the default html5 media player of wordpress. Since an automatic update of Wordpress in August, this doesn't work anymore. The text `[audio src=path/file.mp3]` is now displayed on the webpage, instead of the mp3 player.

I guess this is due to a new security feature of wordpress.

How can I get the media player back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to update your shortcode function to generate the audio player using proper HTML markup instead of returning the raw shortcode text. Here's an example:

```
function myshortcode_shortcode() {
    $audio_url = 'path/file.mp3';
    $audio_markup = '<audio controls><source src="' . esc_url($audio_url) . '" type="audio/mp3"></audio>';
    return $audio_markup;
}
```

Comment: That's what I did. I hoped there was a way to do this using a wordpress tag.